# Showing that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=k) = \frac{(1-p)^k}{k\log(1/p)}\quad k\in\mathbb{N}$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with the logarithmic mass function
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1=k) = \frac{(1-p)^k}{k \log(1/p)}, \quad k \in \mathbb{N} \quad (1)
$$

,where $0 < p < 1$.

(i) Show that (1) is a distribution on the Set $\mathbb{N}$.

(ii) Let $N$~Poi$(\alpha)$ with the parameter $\alpha>0$. Show that
$$
S_N := \sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i
$$
is negatively binomially distributed if $N$ and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are independent.

I am somewhat confused by what I am meant to do for (i) my idea is to compute the Probability Generating Function(pdf), but after doing so I am not sure how to argue why it in fact is a distribution. For question (ii) I am quite sure I could solve it using Probability Generating Functions, as well as their composition.

Comment: For (i) you just need to show that $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} P(X_1=k) = 1$

Comment: Do you perhaps any tips on how to show that? I've tried subbing $(1-p)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}(-p)^k$ into the series, which didn't work out

Comment: It's an infinite sum so you need to use the taylor expansion for $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why I would use the Taylor expansion for log(1+x)? I understand that $\log(1+x)$ is more or less equal to $\log(1/p)$, but how will I eliminate terms? Should I also use what I tried subbing into the formula with the Taylor Expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $(1)$ is a distribution you need to show
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X_1=k) = 1$$

or equivalently that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{k} = \log(1/p)$$

Now write $\log(1/p)=-\log (p)=-\log(1+(p-1))$. Since $|p-1|\leq 1$ we can use the [Taylor series expansion for $\log(1+x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) to get

$$\log(1/p) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(p-1)^k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(p-1)^k}{k}$$
thus proving that $(1)$ is actually a distribution on $\mathbb{N}$.